# AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?

Tags: pandas

I am getting this error while splitting a column in Dataframe. I have explicitly converted the column to string but still I am getting this error. Am I missing anything here.

I got successful conversion on

```
df['name'] = df['employee'].astype(str).str.split(',').str[0].str.replace("{'name': ", "").str.replace("'", "").str.strip()
```

[image]

But I am getting error for the any of the below below code

```
df['email'] = df['employee'].astype(str).str.split(',').str[2].str.replace("{'email': ", "").str.replace("'", "").str.replace("email: ", "").str.strip()
```

I am not sure why the first got success while the second got failure. I want None to be populated in email column as well.

Note:
I got success when the employee column has a value on at least in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
>>> df
                                employee
0  {'name': 'Louis', 'email': 'l@g.com'}
1                       {'name': 'Paul'}
```

If `employee` column contains real python dict, you can use:

```
df['name'] = df['employee'].str['name']
df['email'] = df['employee'].str['email']
print(df)

# Output
                                employee   name    email
0  {'name': 'Louis', 'email': 'l@g.com'}  Louis  l@g.com
1                       {'name': 'Paul'}   Paul     None

# Alternative
# df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df['employee'].tolist(), index=df.index)
# df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

However, if `employee` column contains string looks like real python dict, you have to preprocess your data before with `ast.literal_eval` to convert string as python object:

```
import ast

# Normally, you don't need to use .astype(str)
df['employee'] = df['employee'].astype(str).map(ast.literal_eval)
```

To check that, use:

```
# 1st case
>>> type(df['employee'].iloc[0])
dict

# 2nd case
>>> type(df['employee'].iloc[0])
str
```